# How to countinue running sound by avplayer when dismiss view

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am doing a music player using AVPlayer. When i close the view the music is turn off. How to dismiss a view and the player play everytime. This is my close button

```
- (void)showPlayerView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^
     {
         self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
     } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     }];

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you get a beginners book on iOS development and run through it. Your code snippet would suggest that you are trashing the ViewController that contains your AVPlayer. You could also take a look at Apple's AVPlayerDemo sample code - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

I used to instantiate my AVAudioPlayer in the AppDelegate, this way it will not get released along with the ViewController.